# Is there a limit for a file size when redirecting input from a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true says:

> Reads the command input from a file, instead of reading input from the keyboard.

How large can the file be?

I know that putting `myprogram.exe <arguments>` into a .bat file has a limit on size of batch file, and I wonder if I can avoid it by running `myprogram.exe < arguments.txt`?

Comment: Limits are disk space and patience.  The last one usually runs out first.

Comment: Excuse me, I think I don't understand what do you mean with "I know that putting "myprogram.exe " into a .bat file has a limit on size of batch file"... Nor the .exe file neither the .bat file have any limit in their sizes.

Comment: @Aacini there is a limit on how long a single line in a .bat file can be.

Comment: @Joe: Yes: 8KB (8192 characters). For example, this line: `myprogram.exe < arguments.txt` is 29 characters long. I think you will never find a _real_ case where this limit could be exceeded!

Comment: @Aacini I learned about it the hard way, when the real case came up unexpectedly and my program started blowing up at the worst time possible

Comment: @Joe: I think there is a confusion here. The limit of the lines of a Batch file _that you type_ when you create it is 8KB. You will always know how long is a line in a Batch file because you typed it!

Answer (score 0):

As large as your program can accept from the standard input stream.